# Using Workbox in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, workbox

I'm making a Chrome new tab extension and I'd like to use workbox to cache the requests the new tab makes so that the user experience is nice and snappy. However, I'm unable to get workbox to interact at all with the requests my new tab extension makes.

`index.html`

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <title>New Tab</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cloud.typography.com/6844296/7797412/css/fonts.css" />
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: '#f5f4f3'
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='container'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tab.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`tab.js`

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
  });
}
```

`service-worker.js`

```js
importScripts(
  'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js'
);

if (workbox) {
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.js$/,
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate()
  );
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.css$/,
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate()
  );
} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
```

I see the service worker registered but no requests are served from the service worker.

[image: chrome dev tools]

[image: chrome dev tools]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The cache itself does not seem to be complete.

I am worried about the following contents, so why not write the absolute path once?

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    'https://some-other-origin.com/logo.png',
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'sampleName'
    })
);
```

[Route Requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests)

> The only thing to be wary of is that this would only match for requests on your origin. If there was a separate site that had the URL https://some-other-origin.com/logo.png, this route wouldn’t match, because in most cases, that’s not what was intended. Instead, you’d need to define the entire URL to match.

I'm sorry if you don't get the answer you want.